# rename file in unix for different file in a loop

Tags: shell, unix

i have file like :

```
~ls
N1JRN_S001.csv  N1JRN_S002.csv  N1JRN_S003.csv  N1MNY_S001.csv  N1POS_S001.csv
```

I would like to rename all type of file with current date like

```
03nov14N1JRN_S001.csv
03nov14N1JRN_S002.csv
03nov14N1JRN_S003.csv 

03nov14N1MNY_S001.csv

03nov14N1POS_S001.csv
```

in a loop how can i do for each type of file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will rename all `csv` files in the current directory according to today's date:

```
today=$(date '+%d%b%y')
for f in *.csv
do
        mv "$f" "$today$f"
done
```

How it works:

- `today=$(date '+%d%b%y')`

  This runs the `date` command with the format `+%d%b%y`.  This produces the date in the form `02Nov14`.
- `for f in *.csv; do`

  This starts a loop over all files whose names end with `.csv`
- `mv "$f" "$today$f"`

  This renames file `f` to the desired form.
- `done`

  This marks the end of the `for` loop.

#### Example

Let's start with a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
N1JRN_S001.csv  N1JRN_S002.csv  N1JRN_S003.csv  N1MNY_S001.csv  N1POS_S001.csv  script.sh
```

Let's run our script:

```
$ bash script.sh
```

The files have now been renamed:

```
$ ls
02Nov14N1JRN_S001.csv  02Nov14N1JRN_S002.csv  02Nov14N1JRN_S003.csv  02Nov14N1MNY_S001.csv  02Nov14N1POS_S001.csv  script.sh
```